# Media queries ou múltiplas folhas de estilos?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, resolução-de-tela

Em questão de deixar o site rápido e responsivo, o que é melhor?

1-Usar o Media Queries e definir as resoluções em apenas uma folha de estilo.

2-Usar varias folhas de estilo que serão chamadas no HTML de acordo com a resolução.

Comment: Não estou certo quanto ao desempenho, mas você pode testar o carregamento das duas formas e ver se dá alguma diferença. Na minha opinião sem dúvida usar Media Queries, além de ser mais elegante a manutenção pode ficar mais simples, pois em um arquivo ficam os estilos, ao invés de ter vários arquivos.

Comment: Pode desenvolver em arquivos separados e utilizar uma ferramenta de automação para incluir tudo em um único arquivo.

Comment: Atualmente, é muito raro encontrar sites com media queries em arquivos separados. Geralmente todo o código encontra-se em somente um arquivo CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Recomenda-se usar somente um arquivo de folha de estilos (.css). Segue abaixo uma relação de prós e contras. Lembrando que são só recomendações e observações... qualquer um dos métodos é efetivo.

Prós de um arquivo .css:

- 1 requisição HTTP;
- Mais fácil você não esquecer de atualizar alguma Media Querie específica.

Contras de um arquivo .css:

- Tamanho do arquivo é maior;
- Quanto maior o projeto, mais difícil a manutenção;
- Necessário soluções JavaScript para funcionar no IE8 para baixo.

---

Prós de usar vários arquivos:

- Arquivo padrão é menor;
- Facilita a manutenção e a organização.

Contra de usar vários arquivos:

- Várias requisições HTTP;
- Piora a manutenção em relação a esquecer de atualizar um item em determinado arquivo.